# How can I update a document with an empty array as a property?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Whenever I have a schema with an array who's elements have a potential schema, I receive an error whenever I try to update the document with an empty array as the value. *How can I provide a schema for these array elements without getting this error?*

**Example Schema:**

```
tags: {  type: [String], "default": [] }
//or
tags:[ {type:String} ]
```

**Example Request:**

```
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate({something:true},{tags:[]},callback);
```

**Example Error:**

```
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'schema' of undefined]
```

**My Environment:**

- node 0.10.6
- mongodb 2.4.4
- mongoose 3.8.9

Comment: I reproduced this with node 0.10.26 and Mongo 2.4.10 and Mongoose 3.8.2, using the code from @Neil Lunn below.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot say that the same basic principle produces the same results:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var exampleModel = new Schema({
  something: Boolean,
  tags: { type: [String], default: [] }
});

var MyModel = mongoose.model( 'Model', exampleModel );

MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { something: true },
  { tags: [] },
  { upsert: true },
  function( err, doc ) {
    console.log( doc )
  }
);
```

And that gives me a result of:

```
{ _id: 5370b44e718592ba9206979c, something: true, tags: [] }
```

Comment: Hmm, when I run that exact code copy/pasted into the node repl adding the err to the console.log, I receive the same error that I mentioned above. I am using Mongo 2.4.4,  Mongoose 3.8.9, and Node 0.10.6.

Comment: @bendalton I just replicated your exact versions onto a VM and I cannot dupicate this. Both your node and MongoDB versions are relatively old, but still there is no difference. You must be doing something else in your code that you are not stating here.

Comment: thanks a ton for looking at this. I can't for the life of me figure out what else could be interfering. I literally typed node <enter>; and copy/pasted your code in. I'll check with others around my office as well. Can anyone else verify either of our results independently?